# Determine the conditional probability $\textbf{P}(X|X+Y)$ given two independent Poisson RV $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Poisson variables with respective parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Show that:

(a) $X + Y$ is Poisson, with parameter $\lambda + \mu$

(b) the conditional distribution of $X$, given $X + Y = n$, is binomial, and find its parameters.

**MY ATTEMPT**

(a) According to the convolution theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
p_{Z}(Z) & = \sum_{x=0}^{z}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(z-x) = \sum_{x=0}^{z}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x}}{x!}\times\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{z-x}}{(z-x)!}\\\\
& = \frac{e^{-\lambda-\mu}\mu^{z}}{z!}\sum_{x=0}^{z}\frac{z!}{x!(z-x)!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^{x} = \frac{e^{-\lambda-\mu}\mu^{z}}{z!}\sum_{x=0}^{z}{z\choose x}\left(\frac{\lambda}
{\mu}\right)^{x}\\\\
& = \frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\mu^{z}}{z!}\left(1+\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^{z} = \frac{e^{-(\lambda + \mu)}(\mu + \lambda)^{z}}{z!}
\end{align*}

Therefore $Z\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda+\mu)$.

(b) According to the definition of conditional distribution, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(X = x | X + Y = n) & = \frac{\textbf{P}(X = x, X + Y = n)}{\textbf{P}(X + Y = n)} = \frac{\textbf{P}(X = x, Y = n - x)}{\textbf{P}(X + Y = n)}\\\\
& = \frac{\textbf{P}(X = x)\textbf{P}(Y = n - x)}{\textbf{P}(X + Y = n)} = \frac{\displaystyle\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x}}{x!}\times\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{n-x}}{(n-x)!}}{\displaystyle\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}(\lambda+\mu)^{n}}{n!}}\\\\
& = \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}\frac{\lambda^{x}\mu^{n-x}}{(\lambda+\mu)^{n}} = {n\choose x}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^{x}\left(\frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda}\right)^{n}
\end{align*}

This is as far as I can get. Could someone tell me how to proceed from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last step, write
$$\binom{n}{x} \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}\right)^x \left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}\right)^{n-x}.$$

Comment: Oh, now I see it. Thanks for the contribution.